# issue with use of SES in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I am trying to move SES send function from my API server to a lambda function, SES works fine in API server, but not in lambda.

Here is the setup

1. send an SQS message to trigger lambda
2. Lambda extracts email params (to, from, subject, email content) from the message
3. uses SES to send the message

*here are the other relevant pieces of information*

1. lambda IAM role has full SES and SQS access
2. from email address is verified (it is not in sandbox)
3. standard lambda configuration (i.e. not attached to any VPC)
4. this same piece of code works fine outside of lambda.
5. I increased lambda timeout from 3 seconds(default) 60 seconds.
6. I have verified the parameters to the SES command are correct

**Here is the code**

```
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";

const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: "us-west-2" });

export const handler = async (event) => {
    event.Records.forEach( async (msg) => {

      const args = JSON.parse(msg.body);

      const command = new SendEmailCommand ({
        Source: (args.senderEmailAddr || process.env.DEFAULT_SENDER_ADDRESS),
        Destination: { ToAddresses: [args.recipientEmailAddr] },
        Message: {
          Body: { Text: { Data: args.emailContents } },
          Subject: { Data: args.subject },
        },
      });

      try {
        const resp = await sesClient.send(command);

        console.log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
        
        console.log(`Email send response ${resp}`);
        return resp;
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(`Failed to send email - ${err}`);
      } 
    });
};
```

lambda runs and exits w/o any error, however, it never executes the line after the sesClient.send() command

`console.log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');`

which tells me that function was terminated during the execution of sesClient.send() call (If I put console statements before sesClient.send() they show up in the cloudwatch logs.

here is the output of the command from cloudwatch

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v10   Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2::runtime:e3aaabf6b92ef8755eaae2f4bfdcb7eb8c4536a5e044900570a42bdba7b869d9
START RequestId: c0a8e260-7149-5934-9246-bf3cc1af54ff Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: c0a8e260-7149-5934-9246-bf3cc1af54ff
REPORT RequestId: c0a8e260-7149-5934-9246-bf3cc1af54ff  Duration: 371.10 ms Billed Duration: 372 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 95 MB  Init Duration: 587.21 ms

any idea of what I am doing wrong here??
```

Comment: Can you show what your `event.Records` are?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: just replace forEach with a for loop, forEach does not play well with async functions, alternatley you can wrap forEach in a promise.all